# used #NoAction, I want a second anchor

Tags: html

I want to give an extra anchor so that when iam on another page and I click on the link I go the specific div. For example I have 3 `<a href="#noAction">` in index.html, and iam on test.html and i click on the second link which needs to direct to the second `<a href="#noAction">`

I tried something like `<a href="#noAction second">` and just use #second but it didn't work.

**Please note**: The divs are set to display:none and it should be visible when you are redirected to the div.

Comment: The `#` should be at the end of the URL, so it shoudl be something like `<a href="second.htm#noAction">`.  But getting it to display, requires client-side script

Comment: It is not exactly clear what you are asking. A link `#noAction`  will target an element with the attribute `id="noAction"`, and `#second`  `id="second"`

Comment: so is it possible to use `<a href="#noAction second">`?

Comment: You can't target two elements with a link. The `#anchor` tells the browser to which element it should scroll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One you use one anchor, you can't use another.